# Required Dataframe in Specific Format as Given in Question

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Have to convert Dataframe in this Format to Format shown below:
     Stats Data is in Dictionary format:

```
 [  Player  Stats]
 0 Sachin   {'Runs': 18000, 'Hundreds': 49, 'Avg': 45}
 1 Ganguly  {'Runs': 11000, 'Hundreds': 25, 'Avg': 40}
 2 Kohli    {'Runs': 11000, 'Hundreds': 41, 'Avg': 50,'Fifties': 50}
```

to

```
 Player Events  Values
 Sachin Runs    18000
 Sachin Hundreds 49
 Sachin Avg 15
 Ganguly    Runs    11000
 Ganguly    Hundreds 25
 Ganguly    Avg 40
 Kohli  Runs    11000
 Kohli  Hundreds 41
 Kohli  Avg 50
 Kohli  Fifties 50
```

Comment: Your problem may be easier if your `Stats Data` is created with some of your codes and you can post it here.

Comment: Weighted_keywords.append([df['FileName'], keywords]) Those are all keywords, Here i have given a sample data

Comment: New to Python: Leaning now only: df = ast.literal_eval(keywords_NG['keywords'][0]),df1 = pd.DataFrame([df.items()])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create list of tuples by list comprehension and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = [(x, a, b) for x, y in zip(df['Player'], df['Stats']) for a,b in y.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Player','Events','Values'])
print (df)
    Player    Events  Values
0   Sachin      Runs   18000
1   Sachin  Hundreds      49
2   Sachin       Avg      45
3  Ganguly      Runs   11000
4  Ganguly  Hundreds      25
5  Ganguly       Avg      40
6    Kohli      Runs   11000
7    Kohli  Hundreds      41
8    Kohli       Avg      50
9    Kohli   Fifties      50
```

Another solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('Stats').values.tolist(), index=df['Player']).stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Player','Events','Values']
print (df)
    Player    Events   Values
0   Sachin       Avg     45.0
1   Sachin  Hundreds     49.0
2   Sachin      Runs  18000.0
3  Ganguly       Avg     40.0
4  Ganguly  Hundreds     25.0
5  Ganguly      Runs  11000.0
6    Kohli       Avg     50.0
7    Kohli   Fifties     50.0
8    Kohli  Hundreds     41.0
9    Kohli      Runs  11000.0
```

Comment: Thanks: This Code is working for the sample Data-set Added here, But Getting Error for my Original Data set

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7e9bb6ef4b76> in <module>()
----> 1 A = [(x, a, b) for x, y in zip(df3['FileName'], df3['keywords']) for a,b in y.items()]
      2 df4 = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['FileName','keywords','Values'])
      3 df4
<ipython-input-7-7e9bb6ef4b76> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 A = [(x, a, b) for x, y in zip(df3['FileName'], df3['keywords']) for a,b in y.items()]
      df4 = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['FileName','keywords','Values'])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'.

Comment: @MuralitharanSathyamoorthy - Can you add before my code `df['Stats'] = df['Stats'.apply(ast.literal_eval)` ?

Comment: Thanks :-) Working

Comment: @MuralitharanSathyamoorthy - sorry, missing `]` - need `df['Stats'] = df['Stats'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: @ jezrael How to deal with if i am contains more columns Country,state